# Использование категорий в Objective-C

Tags: ios, xcode, objective-c, obj

Я знаю что Objective-C обладает возможностью добавлять новые методы к уже существующим классам, однако не очень понятно для чего это делается. Если возможно, было бы супер увидеть на примере для чего это делают. Совсем недавно начал изучение, извиняюсь за такие глупые вопросы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например можно добавить метод isBlank к классу NSString:

Файл NSString+Common.h:

```
@interface NSString (Common)
    -(BOOL)isBlank;
@end
```

Файл NSString+Common.m:

```
#import "NSString+Common.h";
@implementation NSString (Common)
-(BOOL)isBlank {
  if([[self stringByStrippingWhitespace] isEqualToString:@""])
    return YES;
  return NO;
}
@end
```

Пример использования:

```
NSLog([@"" isBlank]?@"YES":@"NO"); // return YES
```

Common - это просто идентификатор.

Вообще категории используются для добавления нужных вам методов, например вы можете добавить к классу UIButton метод, который закруглит углы кнопки и покрасит ее в красный цвет. И сможете использовать этот метод для любых кнопок, не беспокоясь о необходимости указывать конкретный сабкласс.